# CrossRef API Tracing DOI Citations

Tags: python, citations, doi, habanero

I'm using the `habanero` library to retrieve citation information given a DOI.  I've hit a road block when trying to retrieve information about the works citing a given DOI.  For instance,

```
from habanero import counts
c = counts.citation_count(doi = {DOI})
```

will give me the number of works that cited a DOI.  Unfortunately, the DOI's I'm interested in are associated with data sets, so these counts are almost always going to be 1.  What I really need is to count the citations of the work that references the DOI. For example, something like this:

```
from habanero import CrossRef
cr = CrossRef()
work = cr.works(ids = {DOI})
work['message']['references_count']

# what I'm really looking for is something like the following line
work['message']['references_dois']
```

I've been digging through the CrossRef documentation and I haven't been able to find anything that can help me achieve this.

Has anyone solved a similar problem?

Answer (score 1):

About half of the CrossRef citations are available here: http://opencitations.net/index/coci. In particular, I think you need this call: [http://opencitations.net/index/coci/api/v1#/citations/{doi}](http://opencitations.net/index/coci/api/v1#/citations/%7Bdoi%7D)

Please let me know how it goes!!

Answer (score 0):

From the Crossref website on the page [Retrieving cited-by matches](https://support.crossref.org/hc/en-us/articles/214318946-Retrieving-cited-by-matches):

> Publishers participating in Cited-by Linking are able to retrieve a
>   list of items that cite a specific target article. Only the owner of
>   the target article will be able to retrieve cited-by matches.

In other words, not everybody can obtain the doi of the citing articles.

However, the number of citing articles is available in the field `is-referenced-by-count`. See the [api format page](https://github.com/CrossRef/rest-api-doc/blob/master/api_format.md) on the documentation of the rest-api for the details of the available fields.